# Missing android manifest unity 5 mopub integration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mopub

After importing mopub sdk into my unity game and following instructions for integrating banner ads I attempted to build my game to my phone. When building an error came up with this message:

```
Error building Player: FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "C:\Users\000\Documents\Games Made\Game #3\Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest.xml".
```

After attempting to add permissions to manifest and copying the manifest into the folder the manifest file disappears while building. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are copying the AndroidManifest.xml file from:
Temp/StagingArea

to the Unity folder: 
Assets/Plugins/Android before you Build your game.

Comment: I have a problem. In my Temp/StagingArea I only have a AndroidManifest-main.xml and no AndroidManifest.xml. I copied the file that I have and it didn't help.